# FROM clause when reading excel file using OLEDB Data Provider in c#

Tags: c#, sql, excel

How do I modify the below clause to correctly read from an Excel worksheet in C#?

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [#Ticker$]";
```

The pound sign in the FROM clause keeps getting converted to the temporary table "." symbol, giving me the following exception at runtime.

**".Ticker$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."**

I need it to be a "#" as that is in the name of the worksheet. I have no control of the worksheet naming, so changing the name is not an option.

Comment: Try replacing '#' with `_x0023_`.

Comment: @Suraj S: Thanks but didn't work. Get "_x0023_Ticker$' is not a valid name" exception.

Comment: try putting an @ before the string like @"SELECT * FROM [#Ticker$]"

Comment: Won't work, as the c# interpretation of the string is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after some trial and error. The following works.

```
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM ['#Ticker$']";
```

The inclusion of the literal '#Ticker' seems to prevent the hashtag from being converted to the temporary table symbol.

Comment: i tried too, used `DataTable dt  = conn.GetSchema("Tables");` to check the table names

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be to use **OLEDB parameters**.

```
OleDbCommand cmd= new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM @TABLE");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@TABLE”, “#Ticker$”);
```

More information on command parameters, [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can table or column names be parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `#` symbol, e.g.  `string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [\#Ticker$]";` (or double-escape with `\\`)

Comment: @ Mark Thanks for suggestion but did not work, as "#" still gets converted to a "." I will stick with the solution I found...